# File upload unable to Insert form and View on click of file

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have done a file upload for code inside a form and on submit the form should insert into database which is not happening and I am fetching the table in another page and when I click on particular file it is not redirecting to page properly.

**jobs.php**

```
<div id="apply" class="overlay">
                <div class="popup">
                    <a class="close" href="jobs.php">&times;</a>
                    <div class="content" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="" action="upload.php"  id="template-jobform" name="template-jobform" method="post"  role="form" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['id']);?>">

                            <div class="cols-sm-10">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="template-jobform-fname" id="name"  placeholder="Enter your Name"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">    
                            <div class="cols-sm-10">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="template-jobform-email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your Email"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="cols-sm-10">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-phone fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                    <input type="phone" class="form-control" name="template-jobform-phone" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="cols-sm-10">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-briefcase fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="job_name" id="mobile" placeholder="Position Applying For"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">

                            <div class="cols-sm-10">
                                <div class="input-group">

                                    <input type="file" 
                                       class="filepond"
                                       name="file"
                                       multiple/>

                        <!-- <button type="submit" name="btn-upload">upload</button> -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


<?php 
include('admin/config.php');
ini_set("display_errors", 1);


if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']) && $_POST['template-jobform-email']!= '' && $_POST['template-jobform-fname']!= '') {
$sql = "INSERT INTO apply_job (`template-jobform-fname`,`template-jobform-email`,`template-jobform-phone`,`job_name`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db,$sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $_POST['template-jobform-fname'], $_POST['template-jobform-email'], $_POST['template-jobform-phone'],$_POST['job_name']);
$stmt->execute();
}
?>


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button target="_blank" type="submit" name="btn-upload" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Apply</button>
                        </div>



 </form>
    <br /><br />
    <?php
 if(isset($_GET['success']))
 {
  ?>
        <label>File Uploaded Successfully...  <a href="view.php">click here to view file.</a></label>
        <?php
 }
 else if(isset($_GET['fail']))
 {
  ?>
        <label>Problem While File Uploading !</label>
        <?php
 }
 else
 {
  ?>
        <label>Try to upload any files(PDF, DOC, EXE, VIDEO, MP3, ZIP,etc...)</label>
        <?php
 }
 ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**upload.php**

```
 if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))
{    

  $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
  $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
  $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
  $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
 $folder="admin/uploads/";

 // new file size in KB
 $new_size = $file_size/1024;  
 // new file size in KB

 // make file name in lower case
 $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
 // make file name in lower case

 $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);

 if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))
 {
  $sql="INSERT INTO apply_job(file,type,size) VALUES('$final_file','$file_type','$new_size')";
  mysqli_query($db,$sql);
  echo $sql;
  ?>
  <script>
  alert('successfully uploaded');
         window.location.href='jobs.php?success';
        </script>
  <?php
 }

  ?>
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5Ulp.png)

As shown in above image when I click on pdf how can i set correct pdf path for the file so that it redirects properly.

Answer (score 0):

On first look, your opening `form`-tag is not following the HTML-Markup language restrictions. Please note, that HTML (like XML) requires a tree structure for tags, to not get unexpected behaviour.
Example:

- Allowed: `<form><div></div></form>`
- Not allowed: `<div><form></div></form>`

Maybe that could fix the redirection error.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Can you help me with the solution for the problem.